# Adding a text or command after a button click

Tags: powershell, xaml

Need advice on adding a text in let's say `Text_Status` after hitting a button.
How can I also automatically continue the command after a restart to let's say `Button_clearTPM`, then going to `Button_enableTPM`, then going to `Button_initializeTPM`?

Here is my XAML:

```
[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TPM Script" Height="482" Width="479" Background="White">
    <Grid Height="375" Width="382">
        <Button Content="Clear TPM" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,30,0,0" Name="Button_clearTPM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
        <Button Content="Enable TPM" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,0,0,220" Name="Button_enableTPM" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="140"/>
        <Button Content="Initialize TPM" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,169,0,0" Name="Button_initializeTPM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
        <Label Content="Enter Workstation ID: " Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,45,0,0" Name="Label_1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"/>
        <TextBox Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,74,0,0" Name="Text_WSID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
        <TextBox Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,241,0,0" Name="Text_Status" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 

try
{
        $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."t
}
cls


#First Button 
$clearTPM = $Form.FindName('Button_clearTPM')
$clearTPM.Add_Click({ Write-Host "Clear TPM clicked" -ForegroundColor Cyan})

#Second Button 
$enableTPM = $Form.FindName('Button_enableTPM')
$enableTPM.Add_Click({ Write-Host "Enable TPM clicked" -ForegroundColor Cyan})

#Third Button 
$initializeTPM = $Form.FindName('Button_initializeTPM')
$initializeTPM.Add_Click({ Write-Host "Initialize TPM clicked" -ForegroundColor Cyan})

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null

##Possible Commands
#Clear-Tpm
#Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning (Export C:Notbackedup)
#Initialize-Tpm
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? That's not clear with all these _let's say_. Do you want to start with buttons disabled and enable one by one after each process is finished?

Comment: He wants to automate the system i think. I just don't see why you would automate a GUI. Then what's the point of the GUI ? You might as well just write a simple script that does all that.

Comment: Hi all. I am trying to create a script which would deliver those functions into another pc connected to the network without remoting in. I guess ill have to just make 1 button which would do all the task but my problem is on how to carry over to the next command after restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your script doesn't know what your label is.
So you have to make it accessible by making it into a variable.
Then, you can assign whatever text you want via .Content.

So :

```
    [xml]$xaml = @'
<Window 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TPM Script" Height="482" Width="479" Background="White">
    <Grid Height="375" Width="382">
        <Button Content="Clear TPM" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,30,0,0" Name="Button_clearTPM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
        <Button Content="Enable TPM" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,0,0,220" Name="Button_enableTPM" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="140"/>
        <Button Content="Initialize TPM" Height="55" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,169,0,0" Name="Button_initializeTPM" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
        <Label Content="Enter Workstation ID: " Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,45,0,0" Name="Label_1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"/>
        <TextBox Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,74,0,0" Name="Text_WSID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" />
        <TextBox Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,241,0,0" Name="Text_Status" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="329" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 

try
{
        $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."t
}
## THIS IS WHERE MAGIC HAPPENS
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)} # find all names and make them accessible via a variable

#First Button 
$clearTPM = $Form.FindName('Button_clearTPM')
$clearTPM.Add_Click({
    Write-Host "Clear TPM clicked" -ForegroundColor Cyan
       $label_1.content = "Clear TPM clicked"
})

#Second Button 
$enableTPM = $Form.FindName('Button_enableTPM')
$enableTPM.Add_Click({ Write-Host "Enable TPM clicked" -ForegroundColor Cyan})

#Third Button 
$initializeTPM = $Form.FindName('Button_initializeTPM')
$initializeTPM.Add_Click({ Write-Host "Initialize TPM clicked" -ForegroundColor Cyan})

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null

##Possible Commands
#Clear-Tpm
#Enable-TpmAutoProvisioning (Export C:Notbackedup)
#Initialize-Tpm
```